# Unable to Use Windows Update COM object in RemotePS sessions

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

Im trying to change the windows update settings in a remote server using powershell, but when i run the below commands it gives me an error.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Enter-PSSession opalisbinary

[opalisbinary]: PS C:\Users\superv\Documents> $AUSettings = (New-Object -com "Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate").Settings
[opalisbinary]: PS C:\Users\superv\Documents>  $AUSettings.NotificationLevel=2
Property 'NotificationLevel' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.
At line:1 char:14
+  $AUSettings. <<<< NotificationLevel=2
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (NotificationLevel:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound



[opalisbinary]: PS C:\Users\superv\Documents>  $AUSettings.IncludeRecommendedUpdates=$true


Property 'IncludeRecommendedUpdates' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.
At line:1 char:14
+  $AUSettings. <<<< IncludeRecommendedUpdates=$true
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (IncludeRecommendedUpdates:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

[opalisbinary]: PS C:\Users\superv\Documents>  $AUSettings.Save()


You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:18
+  $AUSettings.Save <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Save:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Although when i run it locally on the server it works fine...

Could anyone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work when you connect via Remote desktop and run the commands? It also depends on the bittnes. I don't know the Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate, so I'm just guessing, but - is it available for x64 version of PowerShell? In other words if you run it locally in x64 version and x86, do you see the errors?

Comment: no i dont see any error when i run the command when i access the server via RDP

Comment: Ok, what version of PowerShell do you run via RDP, x86, or x64?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, I could not find a real answer. What I found is [this link](http://myitforum.com/cs2/blogs/rzander/archive/2011/04/18/sccm2012-com-automation-library-from-remote-ps-session.aspx) which states that remote PS sessions can be used with SCCM 2012, but they could not with SCCM 2007.

This does not help you, but it seems that not all COM objects are compatible with remote PS sessions.